# How to convert a tuple of string and tuples into a list of string and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, tuples

I have a created a dictionary key which is a tuple of string & tuples. The typical key looks like

> ("string1", ('string2','string3', 'string4'), (int1, int2, int3) )

I need to now copy the key to a list to modify string2 & int2 and reconvert it back into a new tuple which will then serve as a dictionary key to a new entry.

When I try to make a list from this tuple using

```
listKey = [list(i) for i in key]
```

I get an output that looks like

> [['s','t','r','i','n','g','1'],['string2','string3','string4'],[int1,
>   int2, int3]]

1. How can I retain the 'string1' as it was in the original dictionary key when I convert it into a list?
2. How to retain 'string1' when the modified list is converted back to tuple?

Comment: Maybe you need to only call `list(i)` if `i` is a tuple.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this and should work on your data structure instead (e.g. `(("string1"), ('string2', 'string3', ...) ...)`) but if you do need to you could always do `listKey = [i if isinstance(i, str) else list(i) for i in key]`

Comment: Thank you that worked. But as you suggested, I would try to make the whole key a tuple of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You may only need to call `list(i)`
If not, you could try `(("string1"),('string2', 'string3', ...) ...)`

Or you could use this:

`listKey = [i if isinstance(i, str) else list(i) for i in key]`

Hope this helps solve your problem.